# Vaadin Lumo: Label Letters are cut off at the top

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a Vaadin 14.4.2 application with Lumo theme there are the top pixels cut off in Firefox browser running in Ubuntu (20.10), GNOME 3.38.1:

[image: Text field with label with pixels cut off]

This happens in my applications and also in the Vaadin demo Lumo theme editor: https://demo.vaadin.com/lumo-editor/

I guess that this behavior is because of the Lumo font family variable:
`--lumo-font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Roboto", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";` and because something (I don't know what it is) limits the size of the label element.

In my Ubuntu system there is something for "sans-serif" available, but none of the other fonts.

Solution approach: When I extend the list of font-families by e.g. "DejaVu Sans" (which is available at my Ubuntu system) the label looks fine. So this could be a solution.

But maybe there's another system configuration where this font is also not available and the Firefox also cuts off the top pixels. Is there a more general solution?

Comment: Update: According to this https://makandracards.com/makandra/465686-linux-arial-and-helvetica-different-font-rendering-in-firefox-and-chrome there is some font-alias-mechanism in Ubuntu. At the command line you can check with "fc-match helvetica", at which font your system maps "Helvetica". In my case Helvetica is mapped to "NimbusSans-Regular.otf". The @font-face style (entered in my shared-styles.css, into the body element) did not change anything for me. So I further use the extended --lumo-font-family: [...] "DejaVu Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, [...]; in my body styles.